# Custom Feedback Slider widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[image: How can i create custom feedback slider widget in flutter ?]

I am Novice flutter Developer want to create feedback slider widget like shown in attached image.

Smiley will keep on changing as you slide.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried carousel_slider plugin?

Comment: @urvashi Yes i did but yet enable to figure it out